# Repeating an argument N times within the command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting, command-line-arguments

I want to run the following command in one line, `python3 pythonScript.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 argN.......` in linux.

Can I run the command such that if I typed `python3 pythonScript.py arg$x` I would achieve the same effect of having argX repeat N times within the same line where X is consecutively 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you can use the brace expansion:

```
python3 pythonScript.py arg{1..10}
```

It only works with literal numbers, though, you can't use $x as the range end.